# CUDA multiple definition error during linking

Tags: c++, qt, cuda, linker, linker-errors

I am starting to use CUDA and thrust for a project of mine, so I am still new to some of it aspects. I ran into the following problem.

I have to separate .cu files which I want to use with a common header file which has a struct that both of them shall be able to use. It is something like this:

```
////////Global.h
#ifndef global_h
#define global_h
struct globalParam
{
    uint64_t spaceToUse;
    globalParams() : spaceToUse(1024*1024*1024) {}
};

globalParam glParam;
#endif
```

The First .cu file looks like this:

```
////////firstcufile.cu
#ifndef firstcufile_cu
#define firstcufile_cu
#include "Global.h"

template<typename T>
QVector<T> GPUcalculateNormSq(const QVector<T>& real, const QVector<T>& imag)
{
    QVector<T> result (real.size());
    uint64_t maxSpace = glParam.spaceToUse;

    //Some Code to use thrust and using tops maxSpace bytes.

    return result;
}

template QVector<float> GPUcalculateNormSq(const QVector<float>& real, const QVector<float>& imag);
template QVector<double> GPUcalculateNormSq(const QVector<double>& real, const QVector<double>& imag);

#endif
```

The second .cu file looks like this:

```
////////secondcufile.cu
#ifndef secondcufile_cu
#define secondcufile_cu
#include "Global.h"

template<typename T>
double getMean(const T& vec)
{
    uint64_t spaceNeededOnGPU = vec.size() * sizeof (T);
    uint64_t maxSpace = glParam.spaceToUse;

    //Some code to make sure tops maxSpace bytes on GPU
    double sum = thrust::reduce(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
    return sum / vec.size();
}

template double getMean(const QVector<float>& vec);
#endif
```

Now the error I get is:

```
secondcufilecuda_d.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `glParam'
firstcufilecuda_d.o:(.bss+0x18): first defined here
```

The functions above seem similar, but thats becauseI tried to make them as simple as possible. It would be possible to write everything into a single .cu file, but I would like to split it up if possible.

What am I doing wrong with the linker? I am compiling and linking from within a Qt Creator project. Let me know if you need my lines from the .pro file to know how I use the nvcc compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the fact that `Global.h` is included multiple times and each time it is included it provides: `globalParam glParam;`. That is not a forward declaration (i.e. not just a type signature) but amounts to an actual instantiation of a `globalParam` struct. This then, causes there to be two variables both named `glParam` (each corresponding to a separate `#include` of `Global.h`) and that gives you multiple definition errors.

Quick fix: try using `extern` if you wish to share your global variable (then the linker knows that it's just a reference to, well, a 'external' symbol).

Better fix: consider refactoring your code to pass in the global parameter via reference or pointer as argument to your functions. That way you won't even have to declare the `glParam` variable in the header, side stepping the entire issue and making your code more easy to understand/reason about into the bargain.